# Unicode representation in iOS

Tags: ios, file, memory, encoding

I'm saving a file with unicode(korean) in its name and I'm storing the name of the file in memory for bookkeeping in my app. The file is saved fine, what's bothering me is the way the name is given back to me by the OS.

IF I make a fcntl(fd, F_GETPATH, charArray) call on the file's fd, the filename being returned is different to the file name returned by listing out its directory contents. I did some research on the filenames returned in the two cases and found out that the format in the initial case is Hangul Symbols(length of filename in bytes:18) and in the later case it is Hangul Jamo(length in bytes:36). IOS seamlessly works with the two formats, if I do a localizedcompare on the two names being returned it'll return a 1.

When I'm doing the bookkeeping I store the path to the file(including its name) and the length of this path. I'll do a quick compare on these two attributes when a request comes in and return a handle to the file only if they match. The problem now is when the file is being stored the fcntl call gives me the path in Hangul symbols and when the user requests it back the run time gives me the file path in hangul jamo. As I've stored the path in Hangul symbols, the app'll think its a different file that's somehow not created by the user and returns an 'invalid file' popup.

Visually the korean text looks the same in both the encoding schemes, the only difference is in the byte representation.

다른 문서.docx - Hangul Symbols - returned during file creation by FD
다른 문서.docx - Hangul Jamo - returned by the OS in runtime and also if I list the directory contents.

```
    char *fileName1="다른 문서.docx"; //Hangul Symbols
    NSLog(@"fileName3:%s length:%lu", fileName3, strlen(fileName3));
    char *fileName2="다른 문서.docx"; //Hangul Jamo
    NSLog(@"fileName4:%s length:%lu", fileName4, strlen(fileName4));
```

If you run the above code you could see the names are different in their memory footprint. Any idea on how/why iOS is changing the filename at run time from one scheme to another? and also if someone could explain how localizedcompare is returning 1 in both the cases would be great.

Comment: You appear to be using Objective-C so why aren't you using `NSFileHandle`?

Comment: It was a design choice to use file descriptor instead of NSFileHandle (which is a essentially a wrapper around file descriptors)

Comment: But if you need to get the filenames at some point then you are better off storing them with the file handlers rather than relying on that horrible `fcntl()` call.

Comment: the problem is getting the filenames not storing them